# How to create a pageview using ga() function?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, pageviews

I manage google analytics inside google tag manager and I don't have any separated script for google analytics in the head of my website.

I need to use `ga()` function like [this](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/):

```
<!-- Google Analytics -->
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', 'auto');
</script>
<!-- End Google Analytics -->
```

See? It has created `ga` right after google analytics script. But as I said, I don't have any script for google analytics. I have just a script (which is located in the head of my website) from google tag manager:

```
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-{$google_tag_manager_token}');
ga('create', 'UA-{$google_analytics_token}', 'auto');
</script>
```

The problem is, it throws:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: ga is not defined

Any idea where should I place `ga('create', 'UA-{$google_analytics_token}', 'auto');` exactly?

---

It should be noted, when I run `ga('create', 'UA-{$google_analytics_token}', 'auto');` in the console of the browser, it will be created as well. Do I need a `settimeout()` ?

Answer (score 1):

By default, there is no analytics tag set up into the Google Tag Manager script.

You must configure into GTM a new tag for which you set up the type of the tag with "Google Analytics - Universal Analytics" and set up an event to launch this tag. "ga" function will then be available when GTM actually runs the tag.

**One more information here,** GTM send a hit with a prefix (generated tracker name). Sample:

```
ga('gtm1.send', 'pageview', '/page-name');
```

Comment: Thank you upvote .. just can you please tell me should I do that [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dgkt.png)? If yes, what should I write there?

Comment: You're at the right place. The "Tracking ID" is the "UA-XXXXX-Y" one.

Comment: Ok, I filled the Traking Id filed .. just where can I define "create" ? (not "send", "set")

Comment: You don't need to set any "create" as the tag will automatically do this for you. Your next step is to set up the launch event (for example, an event based on URL matching the regular expression ".*".

Comment: Ah, do you mean "unlimited", "once per page", "once per event" ? If yes, which one?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182227/discussion-between-neii-and-martin-aj).